# write an IE XHR proxy in javascript

Tags: javascript, proxy, frameworks, xmlhttprequest

Problem:

- I am looking for a way to intercept `xhr.open()` calls
- I am writing a framework which will run alongside **exiting** code, over which I have no control
- I need to intercept the open calls in this existing code.
- I cannot change the existing code
- I must thus override the **native** XHR implementation for both IE and Firefox.

I have made the following progress:
http://dogself.com/telluriumTest/scripts/xhrhook.js

the above hook works in Firefox but does not bind `onreadystatechange` properly in IE, so the request is made, but the `onreadystatechange` callback never executes correctly.

Can you give me any new ideas on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess [XMLHttpRequest.js](http://code.google.com/p/xmlhttprequest/) is exactly what you need, no?

Comment: yes, it is. you have no idea how long ive looked for this. i wish i could vote you up more then once.. hmmm.

Comment: If you have any further questions regarding the tiny library, do not hesitate contacting me - by an occasion I am the author ;)

Comment: yeah i noticed that. im glad you wrote that. im going to use your lib on this project:
http://code.google.com/p/aost/issues/detail?id=145
you should stop by there, we are always looking for strong JS talent